# Appending deep within a 6D initially empty numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a numpy array:

```
Returns = np.append([[[[[[]]*9]*21]*21]*15]*15)
```

And I want to concatenate something like `[-1.4]` to the empty list somewhere like `Returns[14,14,20,19,8]`.

Basically I want an array of 1D arrays indexed by a 5-tuple. So starting from the empty array above how to I add things to it?

I've tried np.append and using regular Python lists (but that just appends to everywhere). If anyone knows how to do this in numpy that'd be great.
Thanks.

Comment: `np.append` is a poorly named and conceived function.  Learn how to use `np.concatenate` instead.  And don't try to imitate the list append.  Construct a list of objects you want to join, and use one array build at the end.

Answer (score 0):

First, what is this list construction supposed be doing?

```
[[[[[[]]*9]*21]*21]*15]*15
```

Second, `np.append` takes 2 arguments, plus an optional `axis` parameter.  Read  the docs. Without the `axis` is 'flattens' the inputs.  All that list nesting will be lost.

```
In [308]: np.array([[[[[[]]*9]*21]*21]*15]*15).shape
Out[308]: (15, 15, 21, 21, 9, 0)
```

You could just as well used

```
np.zeros((15,15,21,21,9,0))
```

But seriously, you shouldn't be trying to create a 6d array like this, "empty" or not, until you have a good idea of how simple 1 and 2d arrays work.

Without the axis:

```
In [310]: np.append(np.array([[[[[[]]*9]*21]*21]*15]*15), 1.4)
Out[310]: array([1.4])
```

that's a 1d array with 1 element!

With `axis`, `append` is just another way of calling `concatenate`, which requires matching number of dimensions:

```
In [311]: np.append(np.array([[[[[[]]*9]*21]*21]*15]*15), 1.4, axis=-1)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<ipython-input-311-7e075928e74c>", line 1, in <module>
    np.append(np.array([[[[[[]]*9]*21]*21]*15]*15), 1.4, axis=-1)
  File "<__array_function__ internals>", line 5, in append
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/numpy/lib/function_base.py", line 4745, in append
    return concatenate((arr, values), axis=axis)
  File "<__array_function__ internals>", line 5, in concatenate
ValueError: all the input arrays must have same number of dimensions, but the array at index 0 has 6 dimension(s) and the array at index 1 has 0 dimension(s)
```

But if the second is (1,1,1,1,1,1) shape:

```
In [313]: np.append(np.array([[[[[[]]*9]*21]*21]*15]*15), [[[[[[1.4]]]]]], axis=-1)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<ipython-input-313-7f7884f77a89>", line 1, in <module>
    np.append(np.array([[[[[[]]*9]*21]*21]*15]*15), [[[[[[1.4]]]]]], axis=-1)
  File "<__array_function__ internals>", line 5, in append
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/numpy/lib/function_base.py", line 4745, in append
    return concatenate((arr, values), axis=axis)
  File "<__array_function__ internals>", line 5, in concatenate
ValueError: all the input array dimensions for the concatenation axis must match exactly, but along dimension 0, the array at index 0 has size 15 and the array at index 1 has size 1
```

We could make a right sized array with:

```
 np.zeros((15,15,21,21,9,1))+1.4
```

But I won't try to display that!

Alternatively, make an array of the desired shape, and set one value:

```
In [317]: A=np.zeros((15,15,21,21,9,1))
In [318]: A[14,14,20,19,8] = 1.4
```

Comment: Well the thing is I don't know how long the innermost array will be. And I need to be able to access an innermost array by its index (to take the average of it) which is related to a state-action value in the form of a 5-tuple, which ranges to (15,15,21,21,9). This is for a reinforcement learning problem if you're familiar with those.

Comment: In any case, trying to make an array with these kinds of dimensions with some sort of concatenates is a bad idea.

Comment: Actually should I just have a 1D array with values enumerated by a 5-tuple e.g. an element ([1. 3. -1.4], (14 14 20 19 8)). Then use np.where() to find what I need?